# configuration's predicate cannot resolve any valid root items?

Tags: unicorn

I'm new one to learning unicorn i have intigrate .yml files to my sitecore new instancebut getting bellow error how to resolve please suggest me

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to serialize Sitecore content to disk, Unicorn needs the items to exist in Sitecore.

You have specified paths to templates and renderings in the Feature.MediaRelease configuration that point to non-existent Sitecore items:

- /sitecore/templates/ilight2019/Feature/Media Release
- /sitecore/layout/renderings/ilight2019/Feature/Media Release

Create the items in Sitecore at the given paths (if indeed the paths are correct) and the message will disappear.

Comment: Thankyou @sitecorium reslove my issue

Comment: after that i'm click on *sync* getting other errors unable to serialize items ...
master:/sitecore/templates/ilight2019/Project/Website/Page Types (b4fc56df-c930-4503-9ddd-b004a8c000fb)
D:\Lightsingapore2019\Sitecore 8.1\ilightsingapore2019\ilightsingapore2019\build\src\project\ilight2019\serialization\ilight2019.Website.Templates\Project\Website\Page Types.yml
> ParentItemNotFoundException: Exception of type 'Sitecore.Data.Serialization.Exceptions.ParentItemNotFoundException' was thrown.

Answer (score 0):

On my Sitecore v9.1 instance the serialization paths were defined in the following two files:

- \App_Config\Include\zz.Foundation\Serialization\Foundation.Serialization.config
- \App_Config\Include\Unicorn.Helix.config

I was able to adjust the paths to reflect my custom helix layers, I also excluded a few troublesome paths by using `<exclude path=""/>` nodes.

For example:

```
    <configuration name="Helix.Feature" abstract="true" extends="Helix.Base">
      <predicate>
        <exclude path="/sitecore/templates/Sites/TheSiteName/Feature/Articles"/>
        ...
```